# Applying textures to shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

[image]

Hi, I'm curious on how the texturizing effect for the latest DOOM games was achieved. More precisely, what kind of texture was applied to the shape and how would I go about applying it properly?

Comment: Voted to reopen. I don't see how this is too broad. I can explain this with 2 example images tops and a few paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it in different styles, you could find a grunge texture and place it over white text, then make a selection of the text shape and delete the remaining part of the texture, alternatively if you find a vector grunge texture you can make a selection of those shapes and delete it out of the text.

Someone else may be able to explain it better but those are a couple of ways I have done it in the past.